# Hierachial Query across multiple tables

Tags: sql, oracle

I have 5 tables as shown.

Item_Type

```
Item_Type_ID  Item_Type_Name        Item_Class
1         System Group              Group
2         System Component          Component
3         System Component Item     Item
4         Description               Information
5         Further Description       Information
6         Space Group               Group
7         Void Space                Space
```

Item_Type_Relationship

```
Item_Type_Relationship_ID   F_Item_Type_ID  S_Item_Type_ID  Level
1                          1                2                2
2                          1                6                2
3                          2                3                3
4                          3                4                4
5                          3                5                4
6                          6                7                2
```

Attribute

```
Attribute_Type_ID   Attribute_Type_Name     Item_Type_ID
1                   Vertical Location       1
1                   Transverse Location     1
1                   Alphanumeric ID         1
2                   Alphanumeric ID         3
3                   Vertical Location       6
3                   Transverse Location     6
3                   Alphanumeric ID         6
```

Attribute_LOV

```
Attribute_Type_ID   Attribute_LOV_ID    Attribute_Value Item_Type_ID
1                         1                       Upper     1
1                         2                       Port      1
1                         3                       No.1      1
2                         4                       No.5      3
3                         5                       Upper     6
3                         6                       Starboard 6
3                         7                       No.10     6
```

Item

```
Item_ID  Asset_ID   Item Name                 Item_Type_ID
1          2    Upper Port No.1 System Group      1
2          2    System Component                  2
3          1    No.5 System Component Item        3
4          1    Description                       4
5          1    Further Description               5
6          1    Upper Starboard No.10 Space Group 6
7          1    Void Space                        7
```

`F_Item_Type_ID` is the 
father `Item_Type_ID` (relates to `Item_Type_ID`) and `S_Item_Type_ID` is the sibling `Item_Type_ID` (relates to `Item_Type_ID` as well). The column `level` in this table relates to the level within the hierarchy of the sibling (`S_Item_Type_ID`). This table shows how the hierarchy structure exists in the database but im finding it hard to query across multiple levels.

I want to identify all of the `Item_Type.Item_Type_Name(s)`, `Attribute.Attribute_Type_Name(s)` and `Attribute_LOV.Attribute_Value(s)` that exist in all levels below 'System Group' where `Asset_ID = 1`.

I'm struggling to join all these groups together and perform a hierarchy query (using `START WITH` and `CONNECT BY`) between the `F_Item_Type_ID` and `S_Item_Type_ID`.

Comment: Looks like you data for your `ATTRIBUTE` table my be incorrect look close at the `ATTRIBUTE_TYPE_ID` column. Should those values be unique?  If not then where is the `ATTRIBUTE_TYPE_ID` uniquely defined?

Comment: I recommend you post CREATE TABLE and INSERT statements, along with a mockup of the query results you are looking for.

Comment: Around '05 I worked on a project where a tree diagram was spread over multiple tables... the connect-by queries ended up as long as my arm.